# SignalR connection bug

Tags: signalr

I have an infuriating signalR bug. Before I get into details about code i've written, I was wondering if anyone out there has experienced a continuously polling connection.

My client is hitting the server which is closing the connection causing an immediate connection attempt in a nasty vicious loop like this:

[image: Firebug output - ten seconds of activity]

It's effectively causing a DOS attack.

I know that based on simply the description, I probably can't get a definitive solution, but if anyone has experienced this particular behaviour, please tell me what you found caused it. Was it a server error, a js error... both??

I'm using signalR 0.5 and CAN NOT upgrade.

Thanks.

Comment: Just an FYI SignalR 0.5 is unsupported. It's a shame you can't upgrade, there's been lots of issues fixed in both the client and the server. In the past, issues like this happened when a client would have 2 transport instances running at the same time and they would both knock each other out. Good luck debugging.

Comment: Ok thanks df. Might have to bite the bullet and upgrade anyway. Can anyone tell me how painful this might be???

Comment: Most of the major changes are described here http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx